# How to form the structer of a ad on a webpage?

Tags: html

I am about to add some "ad" locations to my HTML webpage(ASP.NET).

My sugestion was to type somthing like this :

```
<div id="adContainer" title="sponsor">
   <div class="title">
        Sponsor
   </div>
   <div title="sponsor">
        [Sponser text with two regular links(<a>)]
   </div>
</div>
```

The customer do however mean that this will not be a good structure for them, instead thay want somthing like this :

```
<div id="adTips" title="tips">
   <div class="title">
        tips
   </div>
   <div title="tips">
        [Sponser text with two regular anchers]
   </div>
</div>
```

How does this matter? Will the first example be blocked by ad-blockers?

For me a tips is a recommendation from me while a sponsor/ad is another company´s marketing. Yes its on my webpage but it dont have to be my recommendation/tip.

What are the general guidelines on this matter?

Comment: "tips"? Really? Oh dear. Advertisers would like to distance their content from any sign of being an advert, both to deceive ad-blockers and people looking at the adverts. Readers, on the other hand, generally prefer to know what is the honest opinion of the author and what they have been paid to say.

Comment: This question could really do with some spelling fixes.  "structer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by simple use a image with a text(sponsor) and then the title tag as tip.